# codeigniter calendar template not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, calendar

Thanks in advance..

I am unable to load the template in codeingniter calendar.

Here comes my code

```
$prefs['template'] = '

       {table_open}<table class="calendar_widget_table" >{/table_open}

       {heading_row_start}<tr>{/heading_row_start}

       {heading_previous_cell}<th><a href="{previous_url}">&lt;&lt;</a></th>{/heading_previous_cell}
       {heading_title_cell}<th colspan="{colspan}">{heading}</th>{/heading_title_cell}
       {heading_next_cell}<th><a href="{next_url}">&gt;&gt;</a></th>{/heading_next_cell}

       {heading_row_end}</tr>{/heading_row_end}

       {week_row_start}<tr>{/week_row_start}
       {week_day_cell}<td>{week_day}</td>{/week_day_cell}
       {week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}

       {cal_row_start}<tr>{/cal_row_start}
       {cal_cell_start}<td>{/cal_cell_start}

       {cal_cell_content}<a href="{content}">{day}</a>{/cal_cell_content}
       {cal_cell_content_today}<div class="highlight"><a href="{content}">{day}</a></div>{/cal_cell_content_today}

       {cal_cell_no_content}{day}{/cal_cell_no_content}
       {cal_cell_no_content_today}<div class="highlight">{day}</div>{/cal_cell_no_content_today}

       {cal_cell_blank}&nbsp;{/cal_cell_blank}

       {cal_cell_end}</td>{/cal_cell_end}
       {cal_row_end}</tr>{/cal_row_end}

       {table_close}</table>{/table_close}';

    //load calendar library
    $this->load->library('calendar',$prefs);

            echo $this->calendar->generate();
```

But codeigniter still loads the default template :( please help me

Comment: I have made a separate calendar for site - admin in the same manner which works fine where as the calendar in the user site is not working as expected.

Comment: print it with: echo $this->calendar->generate();

Comment: Soryy Sir.. There is no problem in generating calendar.. I have already generated and the problem is unable to use the custom template.. it loads the CI default template for calendar.. I request you to read my question again

Comment: can you post your controller code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate the new calender template. So add an additional line given below.

```
echo $this->calendar->generate();
```

or passing through a variable

```
$data['calender']= $this->calendar->generate();
```

For more information [See this link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/calendar.html)

Comment: Soryy Sir.. There is no problem in generating calendar.. I have already generated and the problem is unable to use the custom template.. it loads the CI default template for calendar.. I request you to read my question again

Comment: you have to write the custom css for the template. Else the default template will load.